# Where is ProgressRing Control?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to write a Windows Phone 8 SDK-based application.  I keep seeing mention of a ProgressRing control but I don't see it in the Toolbox or in the xaml designer.

How do I use this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProgressRing is part of the Win8 UI controls, not WP8. In WP8 you should use SystemTray.ProgressIndicator instead which is part of the windows phone UI shell. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2011/06/04/system-tray-progress-indicator.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.progressindicator%28VS.92%29.aspx) for samples.

Answer (score 1):

See below blog link for simple copy&paste code to exactly replicate the Windows ProgressRing (uses the actual style code). Works perfectly, just added it to my WP8 project:

http://briandunnington.github.io/progressring-wp8.html

There is more info about adapting it to WP8 in the answer to this question:

[How to Use ProgressRing in Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171930/how-to-use-progressring-in-windows-phone-8)

Download [this app for your phone](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=d8955478-5a18-47e2-b173-e381fe70e47a) to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

ProgressRing is not available for Windows Phone 7 or 8, you have to use ProgressBar or rather the PerformanceProgressBar:
http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-PerformanceProgressBar-in-depth

Comment: just aa a side note, in wp8 the progressbar essentially IS the performanceprogressbar