# Include Windows 8 namespace in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, namespaces, windows-phone

How can I add a Windows 8 namespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR227716, to Windows Phone 8? I want to use the [ProgressRing](http://briandunnington.github.io/progressring-wp8.html):

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13277664/1758762

Comment: I read those posts. I Just wonder how the guy got it to work on Windows Phone 8 :)