# How to Use ProgressRing in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, progress-bar

In referencing http://briandunnington.github.io/progressring-wp8.html for a fun new implementation of a progress indicator, I would like to adapt the ProgressRing control to Windows Phone 8. I am not sure though how exactly to add everything in the MainPage of my application. What I have is as follows

MainPage.xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ProgressRing -->
    <Style TargetType="controls:ProgressRing">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource AccentBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:ProgressRing">
                    <Border x:Name="ProgressRingRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                        <Border.Resources>
                            <Style x:Key="ProgressRingEllipseStyle" TargetType="Ellipse">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
                            </Style>
                        </Border.Resources>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SizeStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Large">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetName="SixthCircle"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Small" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ActiveStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Inactive" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Active">
                                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Ring"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="E1"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                BeginTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.21" Value="1" />
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.22" Value="0" />
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.47" Value="0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="E2"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                BeginTime="00:00:00.167">
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.21" Value="1" />
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.22" Value="0" />
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.47" Value="0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="E3"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                BeginTime="00:00:00.334">
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.21" Value="1" />
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.22" Value="0" />
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.47" Value="0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="E4"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                BeginTime="00:00:00.501">
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.21" Value="1" />
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.22" Value="0" />
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.47" Value="0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="E5"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                BeginTime="00:00:00.668">
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.21" Value="1" />
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.22" Value="0" />
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.47" Value="0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="E6"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                BeginTime="00:00:00.835">
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.21" Value="1" />
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.22" Value="0" />
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.47" Value="0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="E1R"
                                BeginTime="0"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-110" KeySpline="0.13,0.21,0.1,0.7"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.433" Value="10" KeySpline="0.02,0.33,0.38,0.77"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="93"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.617" Value="205" KeySpline="0.57,0.17,0.95,0.75"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.017" Value="357" KeySpline="0,0.19,0.07,0.72"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.783" Value="439"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.217" Value="585" KeySpline="0,0,0.95,0.37"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="E2R"
                                BeginTime="00:00:00.167"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-116" KeySpline="0.13,0.21,0.1,0.7"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.433" Value="4" KeySpline="0.02,0.33,0.38,0.77"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="87"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.617" Value="199" KeySpline="0.57,0.17,0.95,0.75"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.017" Value="351" KeySpline="0,0.19,0.07,0.72"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.783" Value="433"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.217" Value="579" KeySpline="0,0,0.95,0.37"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="E3R"
                                BeginTime="00:00:00.334"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-122" KeySpline="0.13,0.21,0.1,0.7"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.433" Value="-2" KeySpline="0.02,0.33,0.38,0.77"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="81"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.617" Value="193" KeySpline="0.57,0.17,0.95,0.75"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.017" Value="345" KeySpline="0,0.19,0.07,0.72"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.783" Value="427"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.217" Value="573" KeySpline="0,0,0.95,0.37"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="E4R"
                                BeginTime="00:00:00.501"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-128" KeySpline="0.13,0.21,0.1,0.7"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.433" Value="-8" KeySpline="0.02,0.33,0.38,0.77"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="75"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.617" Value="187" KeySpline="0.57,0.17,0.95,0.75"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.017" Value="339" KeySpline="0,0.19,0.07,0.72"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.783" Value="421"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.217" Value="567" KeySpline="0,0,0.95,0.37"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="E5R"
                                BeginTime="00:00:00.668"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-134" KeySpline="0.13,0.21,0.1,0.7"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.433" Value="-14" KeySpline="0.02,0.33,0.38,0.77"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="69"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.617" Value="181" KeySpline="0.57,0.17,0.95,0.75"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.017" Value="331" KeySpline="0,0.19,0.07,0.72"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.783" Value="415"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.217" Value="561" KeySpline="0,0,0.95,0.37"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="E6R"
                                BeginTime="00:00:00.835"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-140" KeySpline="0.13,0.21,0.1,0.7"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.433" Value="-20" KeySpline="0.02,0.33,0.38,0.77"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="63"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.617" Value="175" KeySpline="0.57,0.17,0.95,0.75"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.017" Value="325" KeySpline="0,0.19,0.07,0.72"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.783" Value="409"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.217" Value="555" KeySpline="0,0,0.95,0.37"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid x:Name="Ring"
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    MaxWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.MaxSideLength}"
                    MaxHeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.MaxSideLength}"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                    RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5"
                    FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                            <Canvas RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform x:Name="E1R" />
                                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                <Ellipse
                        x:Name="E1"
                        Style="{StaticResource ProgressRingEllipseStyle}"
                        Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseDiameter}"
                        Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseDiameter}"
                        Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseOffset}"
                        Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <Canvas RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform x:Name="E2R" />
                                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                <Ellipse
                        x:Name="E2"
                        Style="{StaticResource ProgressRingEllipseStyle}"
                        Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseDiameter}"
                        Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseDiameter}"
                        Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseOffset}"
                        Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <Canvas RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform x:Name="E3R" />
                                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                <Ellipse
                        x:Name="E3"
                        Style="{StaticResource ProgressRingEllipseStyle}"
                        Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseDiameter}"
                        Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseDiameter}"
                        Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseOffset}"
                        Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <Canvas RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform x:Name="E4R" />
                                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                <Ellipse
                        x:Name="E4"
                        Style="{StaticResource ProgressRingEllipseStyle}"
                        Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseDiameter}"
                        Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseDiameter}"
                        Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseOffset}"
                        Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <Canvas RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform x:Name="E5R" />
                                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                <Ellipse
                        x:Name="E5"
                        Style="{StaticResource ProgressRingEllipseStyle}"
                        Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseDiameter}"
                        Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseDiameter}"
                        Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseOffset}"
                        Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <Canvas RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5"
                        Visibility="Collapsed"
                        x:Name="SixthCircle">
                                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform x:Name="E6R" />
                                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                <Ellipse
                        x:Name="E6"
                        Style="{StaticResource ProgressRingEllipseStyle}"
                        Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseDiameter}"
                        Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseDiameter}"
                        Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseOffset}"
                        Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

....

//My original progress bar (which I'd like to change to the ProgressRing)
<ProgressBar Name="ProgessBar" 
                        IsIndeterminate="True" 
                        Height="20" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" 
                        Visibility="Collapsed" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

And a class, which I'm not sure where to place or how to reference in the MainPage. Currently I have placed the class in a folder named `Common`

ProgressRing.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestApp.Common
{
public class ProgressRing : Control
{
    bool hasAppliedTemplate = false;

    public ProgressRing()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ProgressRing);
        TemplateSettings = new TemplateSettingValues(60);
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        hasAppliedTemplate = true;
        UpdateState(this.IsActive);
    }

    void UpdateState(bool isActive)
    {
        if (hasAppliedTemplate)
        {
            string state = isActive ? "Active" : "Inactive";
            System.Windows.VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, state, true);
        }
    }

    protected override System.Windows.Size MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size availableSize)
    {
        var width = 100D;
        if(!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
            width = this.Width != double.NaN ? this.Width : availableSize.Width;
        TemplateSettings = new TemplateSettingValues(width);
        return base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);
    }

    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsActiveProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsActiveProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsActive.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsActiveProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsActive", typeof(bool), typeof(ProgressRing), new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(IsActiveChanged)));

    private static void IsActiveChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var pr = (ProgressRing) d;
        var isActive = (bool)args.NewValue;
        pr.UpdateState(isActive);
    }

    public TemplateSettingValues TemplateSettings
    {
        get { return (TemplateSettingValues)GetValue(TemplateSettingsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TemplateSettingsProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TemplateSettings.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TemplateSettingsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TemplateSettings", typeof(TemplateSettingValues), typeof(ProgressRing), new PropertyMetadata(new TemplateSettingValues(100)));


    public class TemplateSettingValues : System.Windows.DependencyObject
    {
        public TemplateSettingValues(double width)
        {
            MaxSideLength = 400;
            EllipseDiameter = width/10;
            EllipseOffset = new System.Windows.Thickness(EllipseDiameter);
        }

        public double MaxSideLength
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(MaxSideLengthProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MaxSideLengthProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MaxSideLength.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxSideLengthProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MaxSideLength", typeof(double), typeof(TemplateSettingValues), new PropertyMetadata(0D));

        public double EllipseDiameter
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(EllipseDiameterProperty); }
            set { SetValue(EllipseDiameterProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for EllipseDiameter.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty EllipseDiameterProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("EllipseDiameter", typeof(double), typeof(TemplateSettingValues), new PropertyMetadata(0D));

        public Thickness EllipseOffset
        {
            get { return (Thickness)GetValue(EllipseOffsetProperty); }
            set { SetValue(EllipseOffsetProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for EllipseOffset.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty EllipseOffsetProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("EllipseOffset", typeof(Thickness), typeof(TemplateSettingValues), new PropertyMetadata(new Thickness()));
    }
}
```

}

To note, with what I have above I am getting errors on lines

```
<Style TargetType="common:ProgressRing">
```

and

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:ProgressRing">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write correct XAML namespace:

```
xmlns:common="clr-namespace:TestApp.Common"
```

And you need to correct the two lines from

```
controls:ProgressRing
```

To

```
common:ProgressRing
```

You also need to declare a brush before the style itself:

Or just change the reference to `AccentBrush` to `PhoneAccentBrush`.

You *must* specify `Width` and if you don't set `IsActive` to `true`, it won't show at all. You can use that property for binding visibility :)

```
<common:ProgressRing Width="50"
                         IsActive="True"/>
```

Enjoy.